# Is there a way to export an eclipse project layout?

Tags: eclipse, layout

it could be useful to export just the project layout, in a text format, for example :

```
src/main/java
*net.foo.bar
**MyFirstClass.java
src/main/config
*myconfigfile.properties
```

etc

It could be useful for sharing and talking about project organization, without making a screenshot. And it will be possible to c/p a file name or a directory name .

Comment: Now, i have a issue with a javascript file in a tapestry project, which another project (with a maven dependency) doesn't find, and i asked to a expert coworker where does the problem come from. In this case, if i could export the complete project organization in text, it would be useful. (sorry, i know, my english is far from perfect).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find :

with bash :

```
$ ls -R
```

it will export all directory, with all files under.

```
$ ls -R
.:
CVS  pom.xml  readme.txt  src  target
./CVS:
Entries  Repository  Root
./src:
CVS  docbkx  main  static
./src/CVS:
Entries  Repository  Root
./src/docbkx:
CVS  de  en  fr
./src/docbkx/CVS:
Entries  Repository  Root
```

Answer (score 0):

does not the .classpath file from each project give more or less that info you need?

Comment: That's an idea, but i would like to have the complete arborescence files in the export.